# memory overwrite can't perform in windows powershell [Stack overflow vulnerability]

Tags: c, powershell, stack-overflow, overwrite, buffer-overflow

The below program has stack overflow vulnerability memory overwrite attack here too. Still, when I entered a higher hex value or memory address using bash scripting in **Powershell**, it didn't overwrite the expected memory address.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int value = 5;
    char buffer_one[8], buffer_two[8];
    strcpy(buffer_one, "one"); /* Put "one" into buffer_one. */
    strcpy(buffer_two, "two"); /* Put "two" into buffer_two. */
    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_two is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_two, buffer_two);
    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_one is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_one, buffer_one);
    printf("[BEFORE] value is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &value, value, value);
    printf("\n[STRCPY] copying %d bytes into buffer_two\n\n", strlen(argv[1]));
    strcpy(buffer_two, argv[1]); /* Copy first argument into buffer_two. */
    printf("[AFTER] buffer_two is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_two, buffer_two);
    printf("[AFTER] buffer_one is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_one, buffer_one);
    printf("[AFTER] value is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &value, value, value);
}
```

when I entered the code `.\a.out $(python -c "print('A'*16 + '\xaa\xbb\xcc\xdd')")`
it give

```
[BEFORE] buffer_two is at 0061FF0C and contains 'two'
[BEFORE] buffer_one is at 0061FF14 and contains 'one'
[BEFORE] value is at 0061FF1C and is 5 (0x00000005)

[STRCPY] copying 20 bytes into buffer_two

[AFTER] buffer_two is at 0061FF0C and contains 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA¼+ªª'
[AFTER] buffer_one is at 0061FF14 and contains 'AAAAAAAA¼+ªª'
[AFTER] value is at 0061FF1C and is -1499059284 (0xa6a62bac)
```

above the output `0xa6a62bac`(in the last line of output) but I want exact same address as I entered. It works in lower memory address or hex value such as `\x11\x22\x33\x44`